# Laravel 5.5 Custom Soft Deletes on Model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, models, lumen

My posts are defined as soft deleted or not via the value in the `status` column, where: 0 = unavailable, 1 = available, and 77 = soft deleted.

Currently, I add a global scope in the model to make sure I don't return soft-deleted posts:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::addGlobalScope('status', function (Builder $builder) {
        $builder->where('status', '!=', '77');
    });
}
```

How would I modify `softDelete` (laravels built-in functionality) of a model from its default of timestamps and deleted_at columns to use my number/status based system, to work even/especially when using methods such as `->delete()`, `->withTrashed()`, and `->restore()`?

Answer (score 3):

You can check out the model events part of Laravel. In your models, extend a baseModel class that you make. In this baseModel you can add an event that is triggered on model delete. Like so:

```
protected static function boot(){
    static::deleting(function($thisModel){
        $thisModel->attributes['status'] = 77;
        $thisModel->save();
        return false;
    });
}
```

When you return false, you stop the default operation for deleting the model. So this will instead set the status to 77 instead of removing it. Or you could just use that in any model you want to use this sort of deleting, instead of using a base model. I find the base model to be easier for large projects that have a few things that would implement status based soft deletes.

To expand on adding other soft-delete like functions to this model consider using local scopes instead of the listed global one. For example:

```
public function scopeOnlyTrashed(Builder $query){
    return $query->where('status', 77);
}
```

Now when you do the database call

```
Posts::onlyTrashed()->get();
```

you will get the same functionality as the laravel's onlyTrashed() method.

Comment: Would this then on its own then understand things like `->onlyTrashed()`?

Comment: I do not believe so. This just stops the default behavior of trying to delete a record. Of course, ->onlyTrashed() would just become ->where('status', 77) and function the same.

Comment: After doing some further reading into the SoftDeletes class, the trash methods all seem to rely on the deleted_at column of the model. So without that there is no way for laravel to determine what is and is not trashed.

Comment: So I'd have to completely rewrite the logic for softDeletes - any good idea on how to just duplicate that class and make it affect only this model?

Comment: That sounds like a big task for a small job. Since it is status based and not using Laravel's default soft delete scheme, I would just utilize the model events for delete(), and make that global scope you are using into a local scope on the model. If you make the scope local, you can call it when retrieving collections of that model. With a few of these scopes you will have functionality that will act very similarly to withTrashed(), onlyTrashed(), etc. Just call it scopeWithTrashed() and have the query return all models, scopeOnlyTrashed() will return only models with a status of 77.

Answer (score 1):

You need to insert into model usage class:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
```

Also in class declaration you need insert:

```
use SoftDeletes;
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#soft-deleting

Comment: To add custom method `delete()` in model you need to redeclarate method `delete` in model

Comment: Editing the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;` would change the default behavior on all models right? I just need the softDelete functionality edited for this model...

Comment: Just make you own method `delete` in model

Comment: Could you expand on that - I'm getting confused on where and exactly what to put :P

Comment: Make a method in that model called softDelete() that is filled with your logic. If you call $model->softDelete() it will use that method. I would remove the use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes; from that model since you are not actually using it.

Comment: Ahh got it - so basically what I'm doing now except more local huh... My hope is that there is some way not to have to then define how `->delete()`, `->withTrashed()`, and `->restore()` have to work...

Answer (score 0):

You can define a method in your repository like the following:

```
class YourRepository extends BaseRepository {

    public function withTrashed() {
        $this->model = $this->model->withTrashed();
        return $this;
     }
}
```

After that you can chain the same in your controllers:

```
$records = $this->repository->withTrashed()->all();
```