# Laravel Query: implement Eloquent Scope for Query Builder

Tags: sql, laravel, scope, where-clause, query-builder

In the Laravel Query Builder I want to implement something like Scope in Eloquent.
Ref: [Laravel Queries: Adding custom feature like Soft Deletes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55187553/laravel-queries-adding-custom-feature-like-soft-deletes).

I have some complex queries (with joins and what not) but I want to be able to easily apply a WHERE condition that works as follows:

**original:**

```
Select * from t1 join t2 ... join t3 ... etc
Where t1.c1 = x OR t3.c4 like "%like"
```

**wanted:**

```
Select * from t1 join t2 ... join t3 ... etc
Where (t1.c1 = x OR t3.c4 like "%like") AND (t1.isTest = false AND t3.isTest = false)
```

I have written the following method:

```
public static function scopeNoTest($query, $tables=[false])
    {
        if (!is_array($tables)) $tables = [$tables];
            foreach ($tables as $table)
            {
                $field = ($table) ? $table . '.isTest' : 'isTest';
                $query = $query->where(function ($q) use ($query, $field)
                    {
                        $q->where($field, false)
                          ->orWhereNull($field);
                    }
                );
            }
            return $query;
    }
```

It gets run like this:

```
$select       = <parameter driven select statement>
$where[$role] = <array of different where condition based on passed in parameter?
$bindings     = <query bindings based on passed in parameters>  

$query = DB::table('Transactions AS trans')
       ->leftJoin('Buyers AS b', 'trans.ID', '=', 'b.Transactions_ID')
       ->leftJoin('Sellers AS s', 'trans.ID', '=', 's.Transactions_ID')
       ->leftJoin('Agents AS ba', 'trans.BuyersAgent_ID', '=', 'ba.ID')
       ->leftJoin('Agents AS sa', 'trans.SellersAgent_ID', '=', 'sa.ID')
       ->leftJoin('TransactionCoordinators AS btc', 'trans.BuyersTransactionCoordinators_ID', '=', 'btc.ID')
       ->leftJoin('TransactionCoordinators AS stc', 'trans.SellersTransactionCoordinators_ID', '=', 'stc.ID')
       ->leftJoin('lu_UserRoles AS lu_ur', 'trans.ClientRole', '=', 'lu_ur.Value')
       ->leftJoin('Properties AS p', 'trans.Properties_ID', '=', 'p.ID')
       ->selectRaw($select);

// ... Adds code to Only Select records with isTest NOT True
$query = Model_Parent::scopeNoTest($query, ['trans', 'ba', 'sa', ]);

$query->whereRaw($where[$role].$whereUser, $bindings)->distinct();
$transactions = $query->get();
```

The problem with this code is that it does not put the original [passed in] query in parentheses - so the query is ***wrong!***.

The WHERE the code creates is:

```
where 
     (`trans`.`isTest` = 0 or `trans`.`isTest` is null) 
 and (`ba`.`isTest` = 0 or `ba`.`isTest` is null) 
 and (`sa`.`isTest` = 0 or `sa`.`isTest` is null) 
 and trans.BuyersTransactionCoordinators_ID = 1 OR trans.SellersTransactionCoordinators_ID = 1 
 OR  trans.CreatedByUsers_ID = 1 OR trans.OwnedByUsers_ID = 1
```

And I want

```
where 
     (`trans`.`isTest` = 0 or `trans`.`isTest` is null) 
 and (`ba`.`isTest` = 0 or `ba`.`isTest` is null) 
 and (`sa`.`isTest` = 0 or `sa`.`isTest` is null) 
 and (trans.BuyersTransactionCoordinators_ID = 1 OR trans.SellersTransactionCoordinators_ID = 1 
      OR  trans.CreatedByUsers_ID = 1 OR trans.OwnedByUsers_ID = 1)
```

Is there a way to do this ??

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the following line is causing this:

```
$query->whereRaw($where[$role].$whereUser, $bindings)->distinct();
```

I think there are two ways to solve this:

```
// 1
->whereRaw('(' . $where[$role].$whereUser . ')', $bindings)->

// 2
->where(function ($query) use (...) {
    $query->whereRaw(...);
})->
```

Comment: Thank you, both solutions work. I was so fixated on a solution that did not require me to change the existing query (actually queries - I have several that were too complicated to use Eloquent) that I missed this simpler solution.